# Sending reply to existing message using gmail api does not show conversation trail in the gmail inbox

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I'am using gmail rest api using Python. I construct the message using python built-in email library in the following way.

```
message=email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message['from'] = 'Satish <satish@gmail.com>'
message['to'] = 'Satish1 <satish1@gmail.com>'
message['subject'] = 'Same as reply to message's subject'
raw_message = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
if reply_to:
    raw_message['threadId'] = reply_to  # thread id of existing conversation
return raw_message
```

I sent this message using Gmail Rest Api like this:

```
users().messages().send(userId='me', body=raw_message).execute()
```

I'am getting this message as part of the thread which is fine. But unable to see conversation trail attached to the message. 
[conversation trail is something attached with the message as **...** and when hovered it says **show trimmed content** ]

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trail is just a part of the message. The Gmail API does not implement that for you. You could just get the message you are responding to, and put it below your message, with a starting `>` for each quoted line.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.194.176.73 with HTTP; Thu, 11 Feb 2016 07:48:48 -0800 (PST)
In-Reply-To: <CADsZLRyvpU3bVw4MmmqGKTr=4bAAQmrRKj3gABVBWqrr8peoUA@mail.gmail.com>
References: <CADsZLRyvpU3bVw4MmmqGKTr=4bAAQmrRKj3gABVBWqrr8peoUA@mail.gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 16:48:48 +0100
Delivered-To: emtholin@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CADsZLRztKLR0GgUSZxN6+B4pwxZiFi=6Rexq+kBXTYWy1UnojQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Re: Hello my friend
From: Emil Tholin <emtholin@gmail.com>
To: Emil Tholin <emtholin@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1130d08c848a3e052b807cea

--001a1130d08c848a3e052b807cea
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Likewise buddy.

2016-02-11 16:48 GMT+01:00 Emil Tholin <emtholin@gmail.com>:

> Nice to meet you.
>

--001a1130d08c848a3e052b807cea
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr">Likewise buddy.</div><div class=3D"gmail_extra"><br><div c=
lass=3D"gmail_quote">2016-02-11 16:48 GMT+01:00 Emil Tholin <span dir=3D"lt=
r">&lt;<a href=3D"mailto:emtholin@gmail.com" target=3D"_blank">emtholin@gma=
il.com</a>&gt;</span>:<br><blockquote class=3D"gmail_quote" style=3D"margin=
:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex"><div dir=3D"ltr">N=
ice to meet you.</div>
</blockquote></div><br></div>

--001a1130d08c848a3e052b807cea--
```

Comment: Hi Tholle, Now I understand I need to send actual message in this div <div dir="ltr">{{all my message}}</div> and attach trail something like this <div class="gmail_extra">{{trail goes here}}</div>. If my message is just 'Hi' it works totally fine but if it is something like <div>Hi</div> then actual message is going into trail as well. Any suggestions how do I get away with this? Thanks

Comment: @SatishReddy That's odd. I don't know to be honest :( I have never experienced that myself.

Comment: yeah If i put message as <div dir=3D"ltr"><b>Hey buddy</b></div> It goes as part of the trail. (screenshot: http://prntscr.com/a28byv)  :(